# How to apply a function to every element in a dataframe in a list and return a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, mapply

I have a dataframe which looks like this example (just much larger):

```
Name <- c('Peter','Peter','Peter', 'Ben','Ben','Ben','Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary')
var1 <- c(0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7)
var2 <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2)
var3 <- c(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2)
df <- data.frame(Name, var1, var2, var3)
df
```

I split my dataframe in order to apply a function to every group.

```
list_split= split(df[,2:4],df$Name)

my_list=vector("list",3)
for (i in seq_along(list_split)){
  my_list[[i]]=list(
    lapply(list_split[[i]],function(x) summary(x)))
}
```

After that I wrote a function so that if the mean of the values in 'my_list' is larger than 0.9, the difference of the values in 'split_list' is taken, and otherwise just the value. (Please ignore that the operation does not make any sense, my original function is very different.):

```
l <- list()
    fun <- function(x,y) {ifelse(mean(x) > 0.9,diff(y),y)}
    for (j in seq_along(list_split)){
      for (i in seq_along(my_list)){
        u <- mapply(fun,my_list[[i]][[1]],list_split[[j]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
        l[[j]] <- u
      }
    }
```

I want that the function is applied to all values of the 'var's in the dataframes in 'list_split'.
For example for `list_split[["Ben"]]` the values are:

```
var1 var2 var3
4  0.3  0.5  0.5
5  0.9  0.4  0.5
6  0.2  0.2  0.2
```

But it is just applied to the first value of every 'var', so that the resulting list for the first element looks like this:

```
l[[1]]
$var1
[1] 0.3

$var2
[1] 0.5

$var3
[1] 0.5
```

So how can I apply the function to all values in every 'list_split' element and end up with a list that exactly preserves the structure of 'list_split', that is a list of dataframes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try

```
Map(\(x, y) {
   x[] <- Map(\(u, v) if(mean(v) > 0.9) c(NA, diff(u)) else u, x, y)
   x
    }, list_split, lapply(my_list, \(x) do.call("c", x)))
```

-output

```
$Ben
  var1 var2 var3
4  0.3  0.5  0.5
5  0.9  0.4  0.5
6  0.2  0.2  0.2

$Mary
  var1 var2 var3
7  0.4  0.1  0.5
8  0.6  0.4  0.5
9  0.7  0.2  0.2

$Peter
  var1 var2 var3
1  0.4  0.5  0.2
2  0.6  0.4  0.6
3  0.7  0.2  0.9
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this does not take into account the values in 'my_list'. It just looks at 'list_split', but I want to apply the mean to 'my_list' and take the differences or values of 'list_split'. @akrun

Comment: @Mina If I check the length of the list elements, it is not the same i.e. `my_list[[1]][[1]]$var1
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2000  0.2500  0.3000  0.4667  0.6000  0.9000 
> list_split[[1]]$var1
[1] 0.3 0.9 0.2`

Comment: @Mina The `summary` gets the min, max, mean, median, etc.  From your code, you are taking the `mean` of all those?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote in my question, it does not make any sense, I just made it up as an example :D. My original function takes always one value and compares it to another, so I just thought with the mean there is also always one value compared to another one. This is also why I thought the length of the list elements is not important. Please excuse me if my question is confusing, but I am very new to R. @akrun

Comment: @Mina try the update

Comment: I just tried it on my original data and I works, but every time the condition is true, it gives out NA and never the difference. I just tried to delete the NA part, but I got errors. Can I somehow leave out the NA part? :) @akrun

Comment: @Mina The `diff` returns a vector of length 1 less than the original vector.  So, I appended `NA` at the top by concatenation.  If you don't want NA, you can use `c(0, ..`

Comment: @Mina. I tried `my_list[[1]][[1]]$var1[1:4] <- 0.99;
> mean(my_list[[1]][[1]]$var1)
[1] 0.91; and then the output shows for `Ben` 'var1' as `NA, 0.6, -0.7`

Comment: @Mina Maybe you are using the wrong function i.e. `v1 <- c(1, 3, 5, 7); diff(v1)#[1] 2 2 2` i.e. difference between adjacent elements

Comment: So sorry, of course you are right. I just forgot about what the `diff` function does :D. Thank you so much for your help and patience! :) @akrun

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I just realized that it makes more sense for my dataset to take the difference of all 'var's in case that the condition is fulfilled in just one of the 'var's. Do you know how to do that, that is as soon as the condition is fulfilled for a value in ‘var’, the difference of var1, var2, and var2 is computed?

Comment: @Mina in that case, we may need to take out the computation from the inner Map i.e. `if(any(colMeans(y, na.rm = TRUE) >0.9)) rbind(NA, diff(as.matrix(x))) else x`

Comment: I just tried it but I get 0 columns. Could you write the full code? I don't know how I have to adapt the second part of the code.

Comment: @Mina Try `Map(\(x, y) {
      if(any(sapply(y, \(v) mean(v)) > 0.9)) rbind(NA, diff(as.matrix(x))) else x
    }, list_split, lapply(my_list, \(x) do.call("c", x)))`

Comment: It works perfectly! You are truly amazing, many thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
l <- as.list(names(list_split))

fun <- function(x,y) {ifelse(x > 0.9, y-x, y)}
for (j in seq_along(list_split)){
  df2 <- df2[0,]
  df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
  names(df2) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
  for (i in seq_along(list_split[[j]])){
    for (h in seq_along(list_split[[j]][[i]])){
      u <- mapply(fun,my_list[[j]][[1]][[i]][[4]],list_split[[j]][[i]][[h]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
      df2[[i]][[h]] <- u
    }
  }
  l[[j]] <- df2
}

names(l) <- names(list_split)
l
```

This gives:

```
$Ben
  var1 var2 var3
4  0.3  0.5  0.5
5  0.9  0.4  0.5
6  0.2  0.2  0.2

$Mary
  var1 var2 var3
7  0.4  0.1  0.5
8  0.6  0.4  0.5
9  0.7  0.2  0.2

$Peter
  var1 var2 var3
1  0.4  0.5  0.2
2  0.6  0.4  0.6
3  0.7  0.2  0.9
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works perfectly on the example I provided, but I do not undertstand the part with `my_list[[j]][[1]][[i]][[4]]`, so I could not figure out how to apply it to my original data. Can you explain it? :) @cgrafe

Comment: @Mina The [[4]] is just grabbing the "Mean" portion of your my_list summary data.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. However, I still couldn't make it work for my original data as it is a little bit different than the example I provided, but thank you anyways :) @cgrafe